# Selecting value and getting rid of duplicated values

Tags: oracle, plsql

Oracle database

```
create table low
( m1 number,
 m2 number,
 m3 number,
 cr1 varchar2(1)
);

INSERT INTO low
VALUES (35,22,1,'Y');

 INSERT INTO low
VALUES (35,2,3,'Y');

 INSERT INTO low
    VALUES (35,2,1,'N');

INSERT INTO low
VALUES (35,22,9, 'Y');

INSERT INTO low (m1,m2,m3)
VALUES (99,99,99 );

INSERT INTO low (m1,m2,m3,cr1)
VALUES (92,92,92,' ');
```

How I get values if I need to get based value on following condition?

1. cr1 field cannot be 'N',but NULL is ok
2. If there is a duplicate for m1, take the highest value in m2 field
3. If there is duplicate value for m1 and m2 field, take the highest value in m3 field

Also is there a way to select rows that were removed and create a new table with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use analytic functions e.g. `rank`:

```
select m1, m2, m3, cr1 from
(
select low.*
     , rank() over (partition by m1 order by m2 desc, m3 desc) rnk
from low
where (cr1 != 'N' or cr1 is null)
)
where rnk = 1;
```

Result:

```
        M1         M2         M3 C
---------- ---------- ---------- -
        35         22          9 Y
        92         92         92  
        99         99         99
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The query seems to be working but not all data set.                                        INSERT INTO low
   VALUES (35,22,1,'Y');
   
   INSERT INTO low
   VALUES (35,2,1,'N');
   INSERT INTO low
   VALUES (35,2,3,'Y');
   INSERT INTO low
   VALUES (35,22,9, 'Y');
    INSERT INTO low (m1,m2,m3)
   VALUES (99,99,99 );
    INSERT INTO low (m1,m2,m3,cr1)
   VALUES (92,92,92,' ');

Comment: (35,2,3,'Y') should have been included

Comment: @Sxc-Dev No because of rule 2?  22 is highest m2 for m1=35.

Comment: Oh. yeah. you are right. I was wondering how can I get better at writing query in oracle database (sql). Would you be able to recommend any resources?

Comment: Sorry, I've been using SQL for many years now, I'm not up to speed with learning resources!

Comment: @Sxc-Dev as Tony implies writing good SQL is as much a matter or experience and self training as anything else. You ask for a good resource - well you are *looking at one the best*. Look at some of the questions posted here and see if you can come up with answers (no need to post), then compare your answer to those posted.  Also, look at the documentation and what builtin functions are available, Write simple queries against your data using those functions to see what they actually do.  Besides practice for writing SQL train yourself to think in terms of sets of things - forget loops.